# Passing parameter to stored procedure from ASP.NET WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having trouble with passing parameter to stored procedure. No error thrown but desired output cannot be acquired. 
`.cs` is:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (cbRegions.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SectionIncharge", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegionName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbRegions.SelectedItem.ToString();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            dgvResults.DataSource = table;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

`.sql` is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SectionIncharge] @RegionName varchar(50)  --name
AS
select UserName
from SystemUser 
where Description LIKE 'RD OFFICE ' + @RegionName  AND
Enable = 'Y'
GO
```

I've double checked stored procedure working fine in SQL Server Management Studio but when I'm trying to call it from WinForm, no output. Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: If calling the stored procedure in SSMS is fine then the problem is with your C# code, not with the db code.

Comment: Someone has already pointed out ExecuteNonQuery to you...
Also, if you're using LIKE, perhaps you want to concatenate a '%' to your parameter value in the proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `ExecuteNonQuery` (as it can be guessed from the name) just executes query and doesn't receives any output from server.

So of you need to get results you're selecting - you have to use [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) method and process result it returns (see example at the bottom of MSDN page I've linked).

Alternatively, if you're using datatables as source for your grid - you can use `SqlDataAdapter` class and it's [Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx) method to fill such a datatable.

Comment: I've updated the code but to no avail. While dubugging, cursor is jumping from line `con = new SqlConnection("connectionString");` to `catch` statement.

Comment: @RehanKhan If you'll change exception handling code from `catch` to something like `catch (Exception exc)` - you will be able to get exception message in debug time. Probably it is something wrong with your connection string.

Comment: Yes I did that to see the InnerException message and its says: String is not JSON formatted. Format of the initialization string does not conform to specifications starting at index 0."

Comment: Changed `con = new SqlConnection("connectionString");` to `con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);` and it started giving the correct output. Thank you so much for your help.